# Merge google forms date and time into datetime

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script

I have a google form that outputs a date and start time and end time into a google sheet,a new entry into which should trigger a script to make a calendar event.

I'm trying to combine the date with the start time to make one datetime, and with the end time to make another - found lots of stuff on this online but everything results in an invalid date/ doesn't work

I've managed to get the data from the last entry into an object

```
startTime = new Date(eventObject.eventDate + " " + eventObject.startTime);
```

is the nearest I've got- I feel like it should be this simple but understand dates are complicated (and have seen some much more complicated code out there trying to do the same thing) but am now stuck

if I output the above as a string it is "2018-07-24 10:00"

thanks for any help

(ps. I'm blagging coding- have some knowledge but huge holes so sorry if this is obvious)

Comment: About ``if I output the above as a string it is "2018-07-24 10:00"``, can I think that ``eventObject.eventDate`` and ``eventObject.startTime`` are ``2018-07-24`` and ``10:00``, respectively? If it's so, how about giving it as ISO 8601 like ``2018-07-24T10:00`` or ``2018-07-24T10:00Z``? When the last letter is ``Z``, it means UTC. When ``Z`` is not used, the timezone of project is used. So how about ``startTime = new Date(eventObject.eventDate + "T" + eventObject.startTime);``? If I misunderstand your issue, I'm sorry. By the way, can I ask you about ``an invalid date/ doesn't work``?

Comment: AMAZING! @Tanaike that sorted everything!- thank you! Not sure why i was getting invalid date but that sorted it. thanks again

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved.